# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(this).calcSubWidth()')

Tags: jquery

Having an issue with an error related to the navigation menu. When hovering over, a javascript error appears: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(this).calcSubWidth()'). It is in menu.js. However, even with the erro, the menu works fine.

Website: http://csenew.drdino.coresense.com

Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: Posting the relevant code will make it much easier for the SO community to find your issue. However, it sounds like the `calcSubWidth` function isn't available. Since you're trying to run it on a jQuery object, can you double check to make sure that it's bound to `$.fn`?

Comment: I can see where the `calcSubWidth` is added to `jQuery.fn`, but I don't know why you're doing it inside the handler, or why it doesn't show up in the jQuery object. http://csenew.drdino.coresense.com/static/js/menu.js

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at `menu.js` and noticed one thing. You are creating your plugin (`calcSubWidth`) inside of the `megaHoverOver` function. `megaHoverOver` is being called every time you hover a menu item, so you are redefining `calcSubWidth` every time as well. Try moving the definition of `calcSubWidth` up to the top of the document.ready function and see if that helps.

Another comment -- consider returning `rowWidth` from `calcSubWidth` instead of just accessing it as a global everywhere. Globals aren't great to use for many reasons including debugging and a performance hit when traveling up the scope chain.